# Does 3 points on Poincaré Disk geodesic lie on the same Poincaré Half Plane geodesic?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

This may be a trivial question, IMO the answer should be yes.

Given a geodesic $\delta$ on the Poincaré Disk's model with $A, B, C \in \delta$

And given that $f(x)$ is an isometry from the Poincaré Disk to the Poincaré Half-Plane.

Do $f(A)$, $f(B)$ and $f(C)$ lie on the same geodesic $\gamma$ on the Poincaré Half-Plane ?

My implementation shows me that this is not true, but I feel that my implementation is wrong.

Does 3 points on Poincaré Disk geodesic lie on the same Poincaré Half Plane geodesic ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a projection from the Poincare Disk to the Poincare Half-Plane"?

Comment: @LeeMosher : A mapping of every point (bijection ?) in the Poincaré Disk to the Poincaré Half-Plane ?

Comment: If your "projection" is a isometry than it's true. Isometries take geodesics to geodesics. Otherwise I see no chance.

Comment: Actually, you may be fine if the map is conformal.

Comment: Yes 3 points that are on a line stay on a line when you change model how can they otherwise represent the same hyperbolic plane?

Comment: @Willemien : is there something like a proof ?